# Debugging java for loop: skip to a specific iteration

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, for-loop

I'm working on a java project in Netbeans. I have a for loop which runs 29 times and each iteration takes about 1 minute to complete. The problem is in the 29th iteration of the loop. Is there any way that I can SKIP the first 28 iterations and go directly to the one in question?

I know I can put a conditional breakpoint, but that dosent make the debugger skip the iterations, it just notifies me when a paticular iteration is reached.

Please Help! Otherwise, this would take a awful lot of time to debug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the [Java Platform Debugger Architecture](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/). That might help. On the other hand, you could do something like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ...; i++)
{
    if (i == 28)
    {
         System.out.println("Line Found"); //put breakpoint here
    }

    //remainder of the code.
}
```

This should allow you to trigger a breakpoint on the 29th execution of the loop and you can then use the step functions offered by the debugger to go over the code for the 29th iteration.

I have never used the JPDA, and even if I did I think that the most simple and straight forward solution would be to do something like the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a temporary line of code inside your loop, and put a breakpoint on that:

```
if (i=29) {
    // Put a breakpoint on this line (only hit if i=29)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop condition.

```
for (int index = 27; index < 28; index++) {

    ...

}
```

Comment: I'm actually iterating through the loop like this:                  for(String imageToDownload : imageURLList)
But you're right I could get the length of the list and then debug it. Just wondering if there is any feature in the debugger that would do that without changing the code.

Comment: And?  Change the loop condition?  When you're done, change it back.  You're only interested in the second last iteration anyway